# getting error while connecting microsoft sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I had installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express.But after installation when i connect the SQL server I am getting the following error.

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to S-PC.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Please suggest me something to remove this error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the service is not running. Run Services.msc, find SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) in the services list and click on Start Service button.